# Mysql overwrite next rows in select

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following table

| id | name | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | carl | 0 |
| 2 | mark | 1 |
| 3 | steve | 1 |

what I want to do is the first row would override the succeeding row value for flag
so the result would be something like this

| id | name | new_inherited_flag | original_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | carl | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | mark | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | steve | 0 | 1 |

how do i achieve this?

Comment: Join ordered and limited subquery, take value from it.

Comment: This seems and odd requirement given I can see no relationship between Carl and mark/steve

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a subquery to find the earliest `flag` value:

```sql
SELECT id, name,
       (SELECT flag FROM yourTable ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) AS new_inherited_flag,
       flag AS original_flag
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```